# Rectifier and thyristor

Tags: thyristor

I'm wondering as to how a system like this:

[image: this]

acts, when their thyristors are controlled in various ways.

The converters are simple enough, but I'm wondering how the graph made around the voltage going over the resistor \$R\$ would look like when the thyristors are set top \$0^\circ\$ and \$90^\circ\$ respectively.

Comment: On-line simulator: https://www.plexim.com/academy/power-electronics/thyristor-rect-ind-load

Comment: Thanks, that was a massive help. How does the frequency of the current project to the frequency of the sine-waves; is it directly relatable? (50 hz would mean that one complete sine-wave or two converted "mounds" are 20 milliseconds?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several alternative topologies for controlled rectifier bridges. The one in your diagram is called a half-controlled bridge. The associated waveform is shown below.

[image]

Here is the description of operation:

[image]

The above material is from:F. F. Mazda, *Thyristor Control,* John Wiley & Sons,1973

Comment: it would definitely be helpful to include actual text rather than an image of text.